# session null pointer in RichFaces

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security, richfaces

All,

I'm getting the below issue while trying to access the session map:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext() 
        .getSessionMap().put("userSession", session);
```

I see this error when I log in, and then I wait for a few mins, and I click on any button that accesses the bean. This is well before the timeout (which I have set for 60 mins). Can somebody help with this? It's a major show stopper for me...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
      at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(ExternalContextImpl.java:970)
      at com.mounza.common.Util.logUser(Util.java:129)
      at com.mounza.common.Util.userStart(Util.java:159)
      at com.mounza.homepage.UserHomepageAction.<init>(UserHomepageAction.java:39)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
      at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
      at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
      at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:106)
      at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:368)
      at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:230)
      at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:86)
      at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
      at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
      at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:69)
      at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
      at com.sun.faces.application.ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.getValue(ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.java:113)
      at org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.facelets.KeepAliveHandler.apply(KeepAliveHandler.java:76)
      at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
      at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
      at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
      at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:109)
      at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:64)
      at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:131)
      at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:337)
      at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:307)
      at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
      at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
      at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:109)
      at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
      at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:119)
      at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
      at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
      at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
      at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
      at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
      at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:140)
      at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
      at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
      at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
      at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:95)
      at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:524)
      at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
      at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
      at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
      at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
      at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
      at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
      at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
      at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
      at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
      at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
      at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
      at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
      at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
      at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
      at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
      at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
      at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

**[EDIT]**
I have a feeling this may have to do with using Spring web security for the logging in/logging out. Did anybody else see something like this when using spring?

**[EDIT 2]**
I rebuilt the project from scratch, i'm getting a new error, but same problem incase anybody knows:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:2599)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1106)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:355)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:158)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(ExternalContextImpl.java:1152)
    at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(ExternalContextImpl.java:1140)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.get(Collections.java:1282)
    at com.mounza.homepage.UserHomepageAction.update(UserHomepageAction.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: Which Mojarra version exactly? I searched through all 2.0.x sources, but couldn't find the version which matches the line numbers in your stacktrace. At least, in other versions it hints that the session attribute name is just `null`. So that would bring the problem back to the caller, your `logUser()` method. It is setting `null` as session attribute name.

Comment: @BalusC I'm using 2.0.3... But I made some changes to the above post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the relevant part of the root cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:2599)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1106)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:355)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:158)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(ExternalContextImpl.java:1152)
    at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(ExternalContextImpl.java:1140)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.get(Collections.java:1282)
    at com.mounza.homepage.UserHomepageAction.update(UserHomepageAction.java:47)
    ...
```

This exception indicates that the HTTP request has been expired/recycled. I don't have any sight in your code, but this exception in turn indicates that you're getting hold of an instance of `FacesContext`, or `ExternalContext`, or the map as returned by `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()` as a class variable of a managed bean which lives in a broader scope than the request scope like so:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped // Or @SessionScoped or @ApplicationScoped
public class UserHomepageAction {

    private Map<String, String> params;

    public UserHomepageAction() {
        params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    }

    public void update() {
        String value = params.get(name); // Fail!!
        // ...
    }

}
```

You should **never** do that. The bean's lifetime spans multiple HTTP requests. The bean's action method is invoked during a different HTTP request than the bean is been constructed. You should instead obtain thread/request local variables in the method local scope:

```
    public void update() {
        Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String value = params.get(name); // OK!!
        // ...
    }
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: fiddling with the request parameter map like that is a smell. Have you looked at `<f:viewParam>`? See also [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for).

Comment: you were 100% correct, that was the error in my code. Thanks for the help!!